# Joining table to shapefile without creating new shapefile in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, csv

I am trying to join a csv file to a shapefile using a unique field and a python script. Then I want to append one of the fields from the csv file to the shapefile and remove the join.

Is there a way to do this without creating a new "output" shapefile? The shapefile that I am working with is a very large shapefile in a .gdb and copying all of its information to a new shapefile, deleting the old shapefile, and moving the copied information back to the original location would be non-ideal.

Answer (score 2):

- Add a new (blank) field to the shapefile
- Join the csv to the shapefile
- Field-calculate the values from the appropriate csv field to the newly created shapefile field
- Remove the join